# TypeError: Cannot read property 'CognitoUserPool' of undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use cognito and register a user. I have set up my pool and app and I got the poolId and client id. have the following code:

```
 var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); // Tried 'aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk' too
  var AWSCognito = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js'); // Tried var cognito = ... too
  var CognitoUserPool = AWSCognito.CognitoUserPool;
  exports.handler  = function(event, context, callback) {
  registerUset();
  callback(null, "some success message");
 }
var registerUset= function(){

var poolData = {
    UserPoolId : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', // Your user pool id here
    ClientId : 'xxxxxxx' // Your client id here
};  console.log("YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS");
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var attributeList = [];
var dataEmail = {
    Name : 'email',
    Value : 'xxxxxxxx@brunswicknews.com'
};
var dataPhoneNumber = {
    Name : 'phone_number',
    Value : '55555555'
};
var attributeEmail = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
var attributePhoneNumber = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);

attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);

userPool.signUp('username', 'password', attributeList, null, function(err, result){
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
        return;
    }
    cognitoUser = result.user;
    console.log('user name is ' + cognitoUser.getUsername());
    console.log(cognitoUser);
});
  }
```

when I upload and run the above code in lambda test console, I get the following error:

```
START RequestId: 40f2d39f-4b97-11e7-a9c0-ef84b50cec07 Version: $LATEST
 2017-06-07T15:37:50.315Z   40f2d39f-4b97-11e7-a9c0-ef84b50cec07    
   YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
 2017-06-07T15:37:50.414Z   40f2d39f-4b97-11e7-a9c0-ef84b50cec07    TypeError: 
   Cannot read property 'CognitoUserPool' of undefined
  at registerUset (/var/task/index.js:24:65)
   at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:8:5)
   END RequestId: 40f2d39f-4b97-11e7-a9c0-ef84b50cec07
   REPORT RequestId: 40f2d39f-4b97-11e7-a9c0-ef84b50cec07   Duration: 3621.75 ms    
   Billed Duration: 3700 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 31 MB  
   RequestId: 40f2d39f-4b97-11e7-a9c0-ef84b50cec07 Process exited before 
   completing request
```

which says that Cannot read property 'CognitoUserPool' of undefined. so means CognitoIdentityServiceProvider is undefined which is ver strange.
As far as I see, I am not missing anything and also I followed the following link for code example and set up:https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js

for installation and packages I used

```
> > npm install --save amazon-cognito-identity-js
```

and also I installed aws-sdk. Not sure why I am getting the above error. Can anyone help?

Update:

I added the following at the begining of my code :

`AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';`

and I get

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'region' of undefined`

so I think AWSCognito is undefined.

Update:  I got a suggestion to use webpack to transform my code to make it compatible for older version of javascript and also use import rather tha require. So here is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
module.exports = {
// Example setup for your project:
// The entry module that requires or imports the rest of your project.
// Must start with `./`!
entry: './',
// Place output files in `./dist/my-app.js`
output: {
    path: DIST_DIR,
    filename: 'index.js'
},
module: {
    noParse: [
        /aws\-sdk/,
    ],
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json'
        }
    ]
}
};
```

After tranforming my code and running it I get the following:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module './lib/browser_loader'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
  "Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)",
  "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
   "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
   "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:3651:1)",
    "__webpack_require__ (/var/task/index.js:20:30)",
    "webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (/var/task/index.js:149:28)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:156:3)",
    "__webpack_require__ (/var/task/index.js:20:30)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:75:18)"
  ]
  }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in case if anyone needs that in the future:

the problem is "CognitoIdentityServiceProvider" in the instantiation. For instance :

```
new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool
```

the above works if I access the CognitoUserPool directly from AWSCognito.

This way I do not need even to use webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user pool without generating client secret key and using that user pool solved my problem. Hope it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).